# g.Raphael bar chart changing default color

Tags: jquery

Does any one know if there is a way to give assign colors to the g.Raphael Bar Chat?

Have 2 bars, and really need to change the green.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the colors option:

```
var r = Raphael("holder");
r.g.barchart(10, 10, 300, 220, [[55, 20, 13, 32, 5, 1, 2, 10],[17,13,3,5,7,45,2,0]], {colors:["#FF0000","#006699"]});
```

You can copy/paste this code into your console on this page: http://g.raphaeljs.com/barchart.html to see what I mean.

https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/g.raphael/blob/master/g.bar.js

Comment: You can also use rgb and rgba. eg. `colors:["rgb(255,153,0)","rgba(255,153,0,0.5)"]`

Answer (score 2):

try using `attr`:

```
r.barchart(0, 20, 1000, 580, values).attr({fill: "#333399"});
```